# Android Default Listview row Layout

Tags: android

I wanted to find the location of the default listView layout look, so I can copy some styles over to my custom one. Anyone have the link to the resource?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=core/res/res/layout;h=3c81d0a9f3cf1b966ef7e8a8c590bc6a604a944f;hb=HEAD). The list items are the `simple_list_item_*` files.

Answer (score 8):

Default R layout files are included in the SDK.

Have a look in `{PathToSDK}/platforms/{android-platform}/data/res/layout`
(where `{PathToSDK}` is your SDK's root folder and `{android-platform}` is the specific platform you want to get layouts for)